# Auth not accessible in vuex-module after page reload or direct access

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I have an authentication on my nuxt web-app, using the nuxt/auth module. I also use modular vuex stores to handle different states. After I login, everything is fine and I can navigate through the app normally. But when I try to reload the page or access it directly through a URL, the user is not accessible, thus, the whole web-app becomes unusable. I try to access the user object with `this.context.rootState.auth.user`, which is null after page-reload or direct access. Strangely enough, this only happens in production.

I already tried to add an if-guard, but sadly the getter is not reactive. Probably because it´s a nested object. This is my current getter:

```
 get someGetter() {
    if (!this.context.rootState.auth.user) {
      return []
    }
    const userId = this.context.rootState.auth.user.id as string
    const arr = []
    for (const item of this.items) {
        // Using userId to add something to arr
    }
    return arr
  }
```

Is there a way to force nuxt to finish the authentication before initialising the vuex-modules, or to make this getter reactive, so it will trigger again, when the user object is accessible?

This is what my auth-config looks like in nuxt.config.ts:

```
auth: {
  strategies: {
    local: {
      _scheme: '@/auth/local-scheme',
      endpoints: {
        login: {
          url: '/api/authenticate',
          method: 'post',
          propertyName: false
        },
        logout: { url: '/api/logout', method: 'post' },
        user: { url: '/api/users/profile', propertyName: false }
      }
    },
    // This dummy setting is required so we can extend the default local scheme
    dummy: {
      _scheme: 'local'
    }
  },
  redirect: {
    logout: '/login'
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

I resolved this by following [Raihan Kabir´s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60164165/11129782). Using [vuex-persistedstate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-persistedstate) in an auth-plugin, which is triggered every time the server renders the page. The plugin saves the userId in a cookie, so the store can use it as a fallback, if the auth-module isn´t ready.

Comment: Same problem here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The thing is, the `vuex` clears data on reload/refresh to keep credentials secure. That's what `vuex` is. If you want to store data for long time without being interrupted after reloading, you should use **localstorage** for that. But **localstorage** is not recommended for storing credentials.

If you need only `user_id` to keep in the `vuex`, use **Cookie** instead. And try something like this in your store's `index.js` file -

```
export const actions = {
    // This one runs on the beginning of reload/refresh
    nuxtServerInit ({ commit }, { req }) {
        if (req.headers.cookie) {
              const parsed = cookieparser.parse(req.headers.cookie)
              try {
                  // get user id that you would set on auth as Cookie
                  user_id = parsed.uid
              } catch (err) {
                  // error here...
              }
        }

        // perform login and store info on vuex store
        commit('authUserOnReload', user_id)
    },
}

// Define Mutations
export const mutations = {
    authUserOnReload (state, user_id) {
        // perform login here and store user
    }
}
```